# cannot seem to run my jar file in command promtp

Tags: jar

I have created a project within NetBeans with includes a form and a class that serves as a database connection layer. When i try to run this project through the IDE everything launches just fine. The problem occurs when i try to launch the jar file created by the ide on the commmand prompt terminal. nothing happens? it just moves to the next line. i have a manifest file with a class path and main class specified and it looks like so

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_22-b04 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar lib/mylib.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: eopprototype.EOPPrototype
```

when i look at what the compiler says is says To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "/h/USERS/local/pagola/NetBeansProjects/EOPPrototype/dist/EOPPrototype.jar"

when i try to type that command it just goes to the second line without anything happening. Not evena ny errors. I am supposed to distribute this jar file to a shared folder and have it run but i cant do it and i dont know whats wrong. I have NOT added any JAVA_HOME path as my jdk 1,6 is isntalled in usr/bin so it should find it there but i have NOT added any classpath (ide shows two runtime and bootable classpaths) somebody please assist me as i am new to the whole java virtual machine environment

Comment: may i add that i have also not set the LIBRARY_PATH to include the mylib and JDBC sql connector lib that i am using. Could this be an issue?

Comment: add a sysout.println in the eopprototype.EOPPrototype to check if it's really called. Keep going until you dont see your sysout => here will be your problem

Comment: where do i add this code. I have a complicated form in whcih i write code behind action events.

Comment: it get's callled through the IDE so i dont know what you mean by saying check to see if the Mian class gets called. could it be that i have not added a CLASSPATH

Comment: find the "public static void main(String[] args)" method in the eopprototype.EOPPrototype class of your project. then add this line at the very beginning of the method : System.out.println("Main method called"); Build, then run your jar again and check if the message appears in the console.

Comment: hello again. I did as you said and this is the error that it gives me Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
        at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1070)

Comment: a little bit more on the command i typed in the terminal. I am running the java -jar /path to dist folder/EOPPrototype.jar and the errro above is what i am getting. When i remove the path and simple tyoe in the command java -jar EOPPrototype.jar i get the error "Unable to access jarfile".

Comment: add java home to path, as well as the java bin folder. Then start directly java -jar EOPPrototype.jar in the /h/USERS/local/pagola/NetBeansProjects/EOPPrototype/dist/ folder

Comment: hey jocelyn... new developments. apparantley i had not set the permsissions to execute the file on my propoerties(new dumb mistake) and now that i have added permission it shows "Main method called " when i type the command in the terminal but still no swing form launching?

Comment: so i know the main class is being called but still no form launching. THIS SI MY java_home path JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jre1.6.0_06
so im wondering if i should add the java/bin folder too?

Comment: so inoticed when i want to run it in netbeans i run the file called EOPTest and maybe this is why it isnt lanuching. But i am confused at to what exactly a jar is and why i cant run it as jar and also i cannot edit my manifest to change the main class to EOPTest

Comment: good news problems solved. Apparently i was experiencing two problem 1) i did not set the correct permissions to the file(execute) and 2) i had the mifest file set the launch the wrong main class. Apparantley my form is being launched by EOPTest and not EOPPrototype as i had mentioned earlier. i went to project and right clicked on properties and changed it the main class to EOPTest and did a clean and build . Now when i launch the jar my form launches. thak you for your assistance and i still have to get familiar with netbeans forms as to why my default main class was not launching

Comment: ok glad to ear your provlem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant the standard outputs, or other things you printed to the command prompt from your java program. To get that printed on the command propmt, you need to run java in debug mode.

Use

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar myJar.jar
```

to run java in debug mode and get all standard outputs, exceptions etc. on the command prompt.